# Can Android communicate with Window Phone via NFC??

Tags: android, windows-mobile, nfc

I have one question whether two platforms communicates each other via NFC.

Thanks.

Comment: P2P/LLCP are the protocols of NFC?

Comment: Yes, they both support SNEP (Simple NDEF Exchange Protocol; a data exchange protocol based on LLCP). I tested it and it works.

Comment: those guys who closed this question obviously don't have a clue. NFC is still not mainstream, and he question is crystal clear. Closing it because it "is not a real question" is somewhat meh... Just if you haven't heard from NFC doesn't mean it is not relevant folks. There a guys out there who are working on the next big thing...

Comment: And yes, Android and Windows phone can communicate. I have seen it with my own eyes...

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, too: WP8 and Android 4.x.

Comment: the question is not that clear. Yeas, WP and Android can communicate with each other (e.g. to exchange URLs) and this communication is done with SNEP, but yuo have no access to the SNEP layer from your own Android application, i.e. it is not possible to exchange back and forth messages over SNEP between WP and Android. The only thing you can do is to send a single NDEF message from a WP device to an Android device and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With use pf the p2p communication it should be possible. There is also the possibility that one phone will work in card emulation mode and the second will read the data - but this is rather a theory then a real possibility, since you will need an access to the secure element.

I did not check the WP7 NFC API, but be carefull - our experience with that system is that almost nothing is possible, so be sure that you double check the p2p/LLCP API is there and there is SNEP on the top of it...

On the other hand the promising information that the NFC stack is provided by INSIDE Secure (see there http://wmpoweruser.com/inside-secure-provides-nfc-tech-in-nokia-lumia-610-nfc/). Check also this presentation from WIMA:http://www.wima.mc/dan/2012/PRESENTATIONS/willem_francois.pdf. What I am not sure is, if the MicroRead NFC controller comes with SecuRead secure element or not...

Check here for the quite nice NFC stack: http://nfc-smart-tag.googlecode.com/git/docs/FirmwareStack.png

BR
STeN

Comment: so useful links. i am beginner of NFC and do not the secure problems. Thanks for your link to introduce these problems